# Convertig Int to Hexdecimal with two digits without using imports in Java

Tags: java, hex

I have a task to write a programm that converts an Int that can range from 0 to 255, into a hexdecimal that has two "digits". We got the recommendation to do this via modulo and switch-case.
While I'm not really sure if I understand how the convertion would look like in theory, I tried it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int set = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Bitte eine positive Zahl von 0 bis 255 eingeben");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Das ist keine Zahl!");
            sc.next();
        }
        set = sc.nextInt();
    } while (set > 255 || set < 0);
    System.out.println("Danke, wir arbeiten mit " + set);

    String Hex ="";
    int Dez2;
    int Dez = set;

    do {
        Dez2 = 16%Dez;
        System.out.println(Dez2);

        switch(Dez2){
            case 0:
                Hex = "A";
                break;
            case 1:
                Hex = "B";
                break;
            case 2:
                Hex = "C";
                break;
            case 3:
                Hex = "D";
                break;
            case 4:
                Hex = "E";
                break;
            case 5:
                Hex = "F";
                break;
            default: 
            System.out.println("nothing");
        }
        Hex = Dez+Hex;
        Dez=Dez/16;
    }while (Dez<1);

    System.out.println("Hex lautet " + Hex);
}
```

It shows a couple issues, which bases on the fact, that I have no clue how the conversation would work. I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: `Integer.toHexString(Dez)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

- Consider a string of hex letters: `String hexletters = "0123456789ABCDEF";`
- The first hex digit of `num` is `num / 16`: a number between 0 and 15 (inclusive)
- The second hex digit of `num` is `num % 16`: a number between 0 and 15 (inclusive)
- Strings have an `.charAt(index)` function that returns the character at the specified index.

You should be able to piece together the solution from these elements.

Comment: Oh wow okay, that WAS way easier than I thought! Thank you for your hints. It made way more sense than using a switch-case.

Answer (score 2):

This code would work **without imports**, simply by using String's own format method

```
private static String intToHex(int input) {
    return String.format("0x%02x", input);
}
```

This is pretty much the same as use of `printf(...)`

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to think about it, is to think of it in binary first.

A number 0-255 will be at most `2^8`, or an 8 bit number:

```
11111111
```

Knowing this, we can split the bits up into two groups of 4, or `2^4` (which ranges 0-15 aka hex)

```
1111 1111
```

Then it's a matter of converting that appropriately. One algorithm I typically use (and you'll see sometimes on lower level languages) is using modulo and remainders:

```
public String intToHex(int in) {
    if (in < 16) {
        return in < 10 ? "" + in : 'A' + (in - 10); //format our hex values
    }
    //build 1 digit at a time
    int high = in / 16; //our remaining value to determine
    high = in >>> 4; //or, you could also shift right by 4 bits
    int rem = in % 16;
    return intToHex(high) + intToHex(rem);
}
```

You could do it iteratively with a `StringBuilder` as well, but the idea is the same: You simply need to grab a hex-valued group of bits or digits, and convert them appropriately.